# Google Calendar REST API does not return title and other event fields

Tags: rest, google-calendar-api

Google calendar REST API GET method (https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) should return this structure (https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource), unless I'm missing something.

I need to get event title and description to use in my application. I 'm getting below response instead.

I've tried to change event visibility (public/private) and availability (free/busy). Actually, API does not show events with Free availability, for which I don't have solution either.

Here is event edit screen screenshot:
https://www.screencast.com/t/X8bRS8kJDT

```
{
   "kind":"calendar#event",
   "etag":"\"3145149995624000\"",
   "id":"5fnlvcl2msab46p8roqbahhb6g",
   "status":"confirmed",
   "htmlLink":"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NWZubHZjbDJtc2FiNDZwOHJvcWJhaGhiNmcgZWQtYWRtaW4uY29tXzMwOHNycjdzdjdiM28xazRpdjZ2cm9mb3Y0QGc",
   "updated":"2019-11-01T02:23:17.812Z",
   "start":{
      "dateTime":"2019-11-11T09:30:00+11:00"
   },
   "end":{
      "dateTime":"2019-11-11T10:00:00+11:00"
   },
   "visibility":"private",
   "iCalUID":"5fnlvcl2msab46p8roqbahhb6g@google.com"
}
```

Are there other methods to get calendar events details with REST API, including ones with free availability?

Thanks.

04/02/2020:
I actually made it work for "ordinary" Google account - add project, add API, add service account and allocate service account email to the calendar. But I still not sure how to change access level for G Suite account. It allows only to see Free/Busy status.

I've changed default access in Admin Console as this article suggests, but it does not help:
https://www.macworld.com/article/2980005/the-mystery-of-the-unsharable-google-apps-calendar.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying the fields you want to retrieve like the image below:

[image]

Or you could put a **" * "** as the image below to retrieve all values:

[image]

***fields*** is a standard Query parameter, which specifies what values you want to include in your response. To learn more about it, you can check [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/query-parameters).

Comment: I've been busy with other projects to check this answer earlier.
I've tried above and I can see fields in Try this API, bit not in response for my code. I see that Try this API returns "accessRole" as "owner", but code returns "freeBusyReader". This could be the reason, but I'm not sure where to give more access
Service account has "owner" role for the project, but it should be for calendar, I suppose.